# Segmentation fault when I change directory in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok, cd, chdir

I want to make a program that imitates the use of cd in UNIX. Obviously the best option is `chdir`. However when the user types `cd /home` I get `Segmentation fault`. When I use gdb, it prints:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. __rawmemchr_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memchr-avx2.S:61
61  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memchr-avx2.S: The file of directory does not exist.
```

The code looks like this:

```
void cd(char buff[]){
     if(chdir(buff)==-1){
          printf("Problem with directory\n");
     }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char* token;
    char buffer[256];

    printf("Welcome user\n");
    sscanf("%s",buffer);
    token=strtok(buff," ");
    if(strcmp(token,"cd")==0||strcmp(token,"cd\n")==0){
        cd(strtok(NULL," ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Than you for your time.

Comment: `sscanf` -> `scanf`. Suggest you compile with `-Wall` and heed the warnings. Also, this can't be your real code as `buff` is used in `main` but is undefined.

Comment: this program does not compile as of now

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You forgot to use `backtrace` with `gdb`

Answer (score 0):

You have made a few syntactic and logical mistakes inside the provided code, like for example `buff` instead of `buffer` in `main()`and `sscanf` instead of `scanf` for giving the input string.

Also, you wrote `cd(strtok(NULL," ");` but a closing brace is missing for this statement to compile: `cd(strtok(NULL," "));`.

I've corrected the code and the output file runs fine on my platform - with GCC on Ubuntu GNU/Linux.

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void cd(char buff[]){
     if(chdir(buff)==-1){
          printf("Problem with directory\n");
     }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char* token;
    char buffer[256];

    printf("Welcome user\n");
    scanf("%s",buffer);
    token=strtok(buffer," ");
    if(strcmp(token,"cd")==0||strcmp(token,"cd\n")==0){
        cd(strtok(NULL," "));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Try it with this.

Answer (score 0):

This code has several problems:

1) even if `sscanf` is swapped for `scanf`, it does not do what you probably expect it to (read the whole line inserted by the user). `scanf` with `%s` will read up to the first whitespace. So, your buffer will actually contain `cd\0` instead of `cd /home\0` like you expect it to. Use `fgets` instead.

2) You must check that `strtok` does not return a NULL pointer. This is what is currently causing your segfault.

Something like this:

```
void cd(char buff[]) {
     if(chdir(buff) == -1) {
          printf("Problem with directory\n");
     }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char* token;
    char buffer[256];

    printf("Welcome user\n");
    // reads the whole line into buffer
    fgets(buffer, 256, stdin);
    token = strtok(buffer, " ");

    if (strcmp(token, "cd") == 0){
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        // we must check if there are any tokens left
        if (token != NULL) {
            // we must remove the trailing newline character that is included by fgets
            cd(strtok(token, "\n"));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```